# Updating HTML data attribute correctly but changes not being displayed on page

Tags: jquery, html

I have this HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="query" data-source="whatever">
```

I have some jQuery that changes the data attribute successfully i.e. "whatever" changes to "test"

```
$(function() {
    $('#query').data('source', 'test');
    console.log($('#query').data());
});
```

but if I inspect the page using Chrome, the data attribute has not been updated in the element.. I can print it in console, but I can't inspect the new value!  Very confusion.  Any ideas?

here is the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/r5YV9/7/)

Comment: jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/r5YV9/7/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The data isn't stored on the element (use attr or prop for that). Instead jQuery maintains it in $.cache.

Comment: `$('#query').data()` gives the map of all the data attributes stored with the element take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/r5YV9/10/. You don't have to use `prop` or `attr` to access them.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing anything crazy like using the data attribute to apply style (no, it's not really crazy) then you need both jQuery's cache *and* the DOM to update.

Swap out the jQuery

```
$element.data(key, value);
```

which won't update the DOM to a method that does both

```
var data = function($element, key, value) {
    $element.data(key, value);
    $element.attr('data-'+key, value);
}

data($element, key, value);
```

*Note:* I always put $ in front of jQuery variables, in case anyone is confused about that. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle you have this code.

```
$(function() {
    $('#query') = $('#query').data('source', 'test');
    console.log($('#query').data());
});
```

which has error ("Invalid left-hand side in assignment"), because `$('#query')` is a function call and you are assinging the response of `.data('source', 'test')` to it.

Change it to

```
$(function() {
    $('#query').data('source', 'test');
    console.log($('#query').data());
});
```

it will work fine.

Take a look http://jsfiddle.net/r5YV9/10/

Answer (score 0):

Refer to Jquery Documentation about `data()` please and you'll see there:

> Using the data() method to update data does not affect attributes in
>   the DOM. To set a data-* attribute value, use attr.

So, you should use

```
$('#query').attr('data-source', 'test');
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery `data()` stores the information in locally defined function data. Whereas jQuery `attr()` stores the information directly on the element in attributes that are publicly visible upon inspection.

So when you use jQuery `data()`, the data is not accessible from outside of jQuery directly and it will not be visible upon inspection.